# Is there a better method to test individual methods of a class

Tags: javascript, reactjs, unit-testing, jasmine, jestjs

I have a component class containing several methods. I would like to be able to test each of these methods individually. So far I have tried to export each individually to test and add them to the class after their creation, like:

```
export const getStrFun = () => 'lorem ip'
export const getNumFun = n => n
export const getJsxFun = (el, i) => <li key={i}>{el}</li>
class MyClass extends Component {
  getStrFun = getStrFun
  getNumFun = getNumFun
  getJsxFun = getJsxFun
  render() {
    return (
      <section>
        <p>{this.getStrFun()}</p>
        <p>{this.getNumFun(2)}</p>
        <ol>{['abc', '123', 'αβγ'].map(this.getJsxFun)}</ol>
      </section>
    )
  }
}

export default MyClass
```

And then in *myClass.test.js* have my tests set up

```
import MyClass, { getStrFun, getNumFun } from '../MyClass'

describe('<MyClass', () => {
  it('should render the component', () => {
    const component = renderer.create(<MyClass />)
    const tree = component.toJSON()
    expect(tree).toMatchSnapshot()
  })

  it('should return the number it is given', () => {
    const number = 100
    const result = getNumFun(number)
    expect(result).toEqual(number)
  })

  it('should return a string', () => {
    const result = getStrFun()
    expect(result).toEqual(expect.any(String))
  })
})
```

Seems to work:

```
<MyClass
  ✓ should render the component (16ms)
  ✓ should return the number it is given (1ms)
  ✓ should return a string (1ms)
```

I've not seen an approach like this elsewhere, but I've also not found a lot on how to test methods that exist within a class, so

What is the canonical way to test individual methods of a React Class?

## Edit

These tests are simple and don't serve any useful purpose; they're just a demonstration of the idea. I'm not asking about their usefulness or how to design tests for them.

Comment: You may want to reword the question to say something like "How do I write my tests to avoid <whatever bothers you about your current aproach>".  Currently your question will gather opinions rather than answers.

Comment: @aaaaaa That's a good point. Thanks.

Comment: What's the purpose of functions like `getNumFun`?

Comment: @k0pernikus only to demonstrate this idea, not perform any meaningful real-world purpose

Comment: Are you using `enyzme`? Then you can shallow render a component and call `wrapper.instance().myMethod()` to call and test the method individually.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have been following an approach to test the methods of a component. You can use this approach if you are using [`enzyme`](http://airbnb.io/enzyme/docs/api/). For this, You need to shallow render the component using `enzyme`'s `shallow` and then call `instance().myMethod()` to call the method named `myMethod`.

Here is a small example.

React Component:

```
class Welcome extends React.Component {
    sayHello = () => {
       return(
           <h1>Hey there!</h1>
       );
    }

    sayBye = () => {
        return "Bye Bye!!"
    }

    render() {
        return(
            <div>{this.sayHello()}</div>
        );
    }
}
```

Test suite for the above component: (Assuming you are using `jest` and `enzyme`.)

```
import {shallow} from 'enzyme';

describe('Test sayHello and sayBye method', () => {
   const componentTree = shallow(
       <Welcome />
   );

   it('should display a greeting message', () => {
       const returnedValue = shallow(componentTree.instance().sayHello());
       expect(returnedValue.text()).toEqual('Hey there!');
       expect(returnedValue.find('h1').length).toBe(1);
   });
});
```

One thing to note here is that our `sayHello` method is returning a `JSX` element, and that is why we are shallow rendering it again to take advantage of [shallow rendering api](http://airbnb.io/enzyme/docs/api/shallow.html)

If we were to just test `sayBye` method, We can just compare the return value of the method with the expected value.

```
// Testing sayBye method
it('should say Bye Bye!!', () => {
    expect(componentTree.instance().sayBye()).toEqual('Bye Bye!!');
});
```

Hope this helps :)

Answer (score 0):

You're technically not testing anything; You're calling the method, and the function which you've bound to that method, then comparing their results, which are always going to be identical. You've effectively done this:

```
expect(someFunction()).toEqual(someFunction())
```

The whole point of a unit test is to call a function or a method and then compare it to a value you've hard-coded.

So first, put your methods inside your class. Next, call each of those methods in a separate test, then compare the value to a value you've manually put in the test.

```
expect(someFunction()).toEqual('a hard-coded result')
```

Even if the result is more complicated than that, you should always be comparing a hard-coded version. Likewise, testing a class might be something like:

```
let instance = new SomeClass()
expect(instance.someMethod()).toEqual('a hard-coded result')
expect(instance.anotherMethod()).toEqual(true)
```

Comment: yeah this is a pretty simple example. your last sentence kind of restates what i am asking the best way to do.

Comment: If your tests are complex, you may need to break down your components/classes into more testable units.

Comment: I see. What might be an example of what that could be?

Comment: I've updated the answer with an example of testing class methods.